# Magento2.4 : How to setup PWA with Angular

Tags: magento2, setup, pwa, angularjs, magento2.4

I want to setup PWA with Angular. I search but I only found Magento 2 project setup with react. I correctly set up with react but not found the best practice and correct way to setup Magento 2.4 with angular. If someone knows that Please help me.

Comment: What angular version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create this yourself as PWA studio only supports React. You may be able to use https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/upward/ to communicate with your own Angular app.